# getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException in web.xml on line <taglib>

Tags: java, xml, spring

I want to use jstl tag library, for that I have included  tag in web.xml

but its showing following exception on starting apache tomcat server.

```
SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: taglib definition not consistent with specification version
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibLocationRule.begin(WebRuleSet.java:1274)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    ......
Oct 06, 2016 4:31:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/SpringExceptionHandling/WEB-INF/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/SpringExceptionHandling/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 13; Error at (33, 13) : taglib definition not consistent with specification version
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2687)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: taglib definition not consistent with specification version
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibLocationRule.begin(WebRuleSet.java:1274)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    ...
```

its saying "**taglib definition not consistent with specification version**"
how to check version

..part of web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-app_3_0.xsd"
   version="3.0">


    <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
```

Comment: Can you include your web.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The xsi:schemaLocation - url "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-app_3_0.xsd" does not contain a schema .. Try "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"

Answer (score 0):

web-app_3_0.xsd type is different from web-app_2_5.xsd, see:
[jsp_2_2.xsd](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/jsp_2_2.xsd)
defined as jsp-configType linked over:
[web-common_3_0.xsd](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-common_3_0.xsd)
for `<taglib>` definition:

```
<jsp-config>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>     
</jsp-config>
```